# Error "A PHP Error was encountered"

Tags: php

Error is:

```
Error
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: admin/orders.php
```

Where my error?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h6 class="panel-title">Заказы</h6></div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Примечание</th>
        <th>Дата</th>
                <th>Товар</th>
            <th style="min-width:70px;">Кол-во</th>
                <th>Цена</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>IP</th>
            <th>Скачать</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<? if(count($orders)): 
       foreach($orders as $order): ?>
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $order->id; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $order->bill; ?></td>
                <td style="font-size:11px;"><? echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$order->date); ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:11px;"><? echo $order->name; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $order->count; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $order->price.' '.$order->fund; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $order->email; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $order->ip_address; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a download="" href="/payorder/<? echo $order->bill; ?>.txt" class="btn btn-default btn-icon btn-xs tip" title="" data-original-title="Скачать купленный товар"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                </td>

            </tr>
<?     endforeach; ?>
<? else: ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">Покупки отсутствуют</td>
            </tr>
<? endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added your code to the question as you should have done. Now you can try formatting it so it is readable, never mind I have done that too

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening on one of the lines in this script?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: admin/orders.php
Line Number: 25

Comment: So which line is line 25?? Please indicate this somehow on you question

Comment: I suggest you add a `print_r($orders)` to your script. Then check what it is made up of. Is it an array? Is it an array of Objects? Is it an array of Arrays?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking somewhere in orders it's not picking it and order is blank,

Try this

```
if(isset($orders)) {
 //Your code here.
}
```